# Chinese Chewing input method does not work on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: language-support, input-language, system-language

I apt-ge installed ibus-chewing and reboot the machine. Now I can type Chewing in Ubuntu search bar, but not else where.  [image: Chewing input method was installed, but it doesn't work.]

I tried LibreOffice writer,Firefox browser,and gedit. I can only type English in them.
[image]

UPDATE:
So I checked out this https://lintut.com/how-to-set-up-system-locale-on-ubuntu-18-04/ and it says *Locales defines language and country specific setting for your programs and shell session.*

I ran `sudo locale-gen zh_TW.UTF-8`, and it only updated the file in /etc/default/locale, which is not the locale used by the system

[image]

Then, I tried `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`. It reconfigure the font types.

[image]
[image]

[image: sudo locale-gen update the /etc/default/locale, but not /usr/bin/locale]

[image: which locale shows locale is not updated. Locale is an executable or recognized data file, not a text file.]

Then I tried `update-locale` to update /usr/bin/locale, but to no avail.
[image]

UPDATE2:

I realized I didn't tick the *Plain Zhuyin Mode* in preference in Chewing.

I can type Chinese in LibreOffice now, but the character selection is horrible, which was always the case.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't like to provide this advice, but try to log out and log in again.

Comment: GunnarHjalmarsson Thanks for the advice, but it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok.. With "Chi" and "Full" enabled I can type for instance 疵　摸 here with Firefox. I don't know what it means, but it's certainly not English. Same with gedit. I'm in an Ubuntu on Xorg session, btw. But I tried it successfully on Wayland too.

Comment: If you don't like Chewing, maybe try some other input method such as `ibus-libzhuyin` or `ibus-libpinyin` (the latter provides Bopomofo).

Comment: Gunnar Hjalmarsson Thanks.  libzhuyin or 新注音 is way better than chewing or zhuyin in word selection.

Comment: Thanks for telling. Chewing has long been the default input method for Traditional Chinese. Maybe it's time to reconsider that choice.